# Infinite loop for network connection

Tags: java, python, sockets, loops, connection

Is it considered a good programming practice to use infinite loop for network connection?

Example:

```
//connect to server
conn = getConnection()
while True:
  data = conn.getData()
  //do something
```

I want to implement this in an efficient manner, such as registering an event and putting the program to sleep. I am looking for an implementation similar to handling signals in Linux.

My target languages are C, Python and Java.

Comment: Try Asynchronous Programming, Try Twisted.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loops are almost always bad. What you want, is an indefinite loop with a graceful way to exit.

Try this approach, illustrated in Python but you can find the equiv in other languages too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import atexit

PID = os.getpid()


@atexit.register
def clean_shut():
    LOGGER.debug("Clean shut performed")

    try:
        os.unlink("module_name.%d" % PID)
    except:
        pass


def main():
    f = open("module_name.%d" % PID, "w")
    f.write("Delete this file to shut module_name cleanly")
    f.close()

    conn = getConnection()

    while os.path.exists("module_name.%d" % PID):
        conn = getConnection()
        # do something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In order to gracefully exit the loop (if you choose to do so), delete the generated `module_name.%PID` file to let the most recent iteration to complete, so you wouldn't lose any data or break your per-iteration workflow.